# Is there a name for the set of outcomes in random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, terminology

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space, and $E$ the set of all possible outcomes. Then, the random variable is a map $X: \Omega \to E$. Is there a specific name for $E$, e.g., the range of $X$?

PS: $E$ is not the support of $X$. The support depends on how the probability measure is defined.

Comment: image or range of random variable. $X$ is also called $E$-valued random variable.

Comment: @ironX Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has already been answered in the comments. $E$ is called the image or range of the random variable.